# Angular2 routing views not rendering properly with polymer (on mobile) using back and forward buttons

Tags: ios, mobile, polymer, angular, polymer-1.0

I am building a basic Angular2 + Polymer seed application (as well as rebuilding personal site), when testing it out on mobile I ran into a few problems. I am using the Router supplied by `angular2/router` and have inserted a `<script src="webcomponents.js_here"></script>` to include `webcomponents.js` after angular **2.0.0-beta.7** (as I write) has been pulled in.

Simplest example I could boil it down to is reproducing the error in the Angular2 Hero tutorial. If you check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/boyjloGS78qw0TGxV9S8) out on a **mobile** browser you will see that when you navigate from one view, to another and you try to go back to the previous view relying on `window.history.back()` as the ng2 tutorial does, you will be able to go back to the previous views but at the following costs:

- The view is not loaded properly
- constructor() gets called but ngInit() never gets called
- If you move the service-fetching logic from `ngInit()` to the constructor (as I did in the plunk) to test to see if the service data is still being fetched properly, the view is still not rendered properly (makes me think there is some polyfill conflict issue stopping the structural directives (`*ngFor` in this case) from working and manipulating the DOM properly. To get the view to load properly and the structural directives to work again with the service fetched data, you have to navigate to that view in any other way but using the `window.history`. This makes natural `Back/Forward` button routing an issue in Angular2 apps that use Polymer. It seems that as of posting this it only happens on mobile browsers.

I am testing on an iPhone 6 plus iOS 9 (9.2) and Chrome version 48.0.2564.104

Could this be some sort of view caching or polyfill problem?